# При import код повторно не запускается

Tags: python, импорт, python-3.7, python-import

Код на python:

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
    start = time.time()
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

    import file1

    end = time.time() - start
    print(time_start)
    time.sleep(86400 - end)
```

Кто знает почему после прохождения задержки не срабатывает код из import file1, после задержки `time.sleep(86400 - end)` получаю только `print(time_start)`? 
Если вместо импорта вставить прям весь код из файла file1, то все ок. Для примера привел импорт только одного файла, но у меня их много и код вставлять из каждого неудобно. Код в файлах не в классах

Comment: покажите ваш код file1

Answer (score 3):

Я знаю, почему не срабатывает. Потому что импорт осуществляется только один раз. Все импортированные модули хранятся в [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules), и если какой-то модуль уже был импортирован, то второго импорта не происходит.

Можно, конечно, использовать [importlib.reload(module)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) (в питоне 2 просто `reload()`), но сама идея того, что программа основана на выполнении кода импортируемых модулей прямо во время импорта, мне кажется неправильной.

Comment: Либо код в файлах оборачивать в класс, а потом импортировать файлы, но в цикле вызывать main?

Comment: @ChikChirik, не нужно в класс, достаточно в функцию обернуть.